# Where instance variables(primitives) are stored in java? Is anyhow stack related to instance variables storage?

Tags: java, variables

Where instance variables(primitives) are stored in java?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Primitive variables are stored in the same places *all* variables are stored (including references):

- Within objects created (allocated) on the heap, or
- Within method stack frames as local variables, or
- Within static areas of their containing class (which are on the heap).

Comment: to put this another way ... instance variables, which are defined to be part of a class, are stored on the heap. local variables, defined inside a method, are stored in the stack frame of that method.

Answer (score 2):

If you mean instance fields declared on a class, they are allocated on the heap as part of the object's own allocation.

Primitive (value type) variables declared as method locals are stored in the method's stack frame.

Answer (score 0):

After class loader loads classes with qualified name into the jvm . JVM parse the binary data from the class and place that info into the Method area. When JVM executes the class it first place the Objects (including instance fields primitive/non primitive) into the heap.